# Scaling smaller images with Fancybox

Tags: jquery, image, resize, fancybox

I was wondering if there was a simple way to scale smaller images inside a fancyBox (2.0.6) container.

Right now my page works fine when I have high-res images, the fancybox scales to the viewport.

What I want to do is if there's a small image (say 200x300px), I want to resize that image to fit the viewport. I'm aware it will degrade in quality, but I still want it to scale up.

Can this be done? I coundn't find anything in the fancyBox API to do this, and no plugins.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's feasible BUT the transition will look really weird (because is not the normal way to work but forcing the upscale)

Assuming you have this html:

```
<a class="fancy" href="images/01.jpg">open small image and upscale</a>
```

you can try this script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".fancy").fancybox({
  afterShow: function(){
   this.height = $(window).height();
   this.width = 'auto'
  }
 }); // fancybox
});//ready
```

PS. use at your own risk

Comment: Thanks, that worked like a charm. I'll just have ti figure out how to maintain the aspect ratio. :D

Answer (score 1):

to keep aspect ratio i modified the above

```
afterShow: function(){
 wh = $(window).height()/this.height;
 ww = $(window).width()/this.width;
 if (wh<ww)
 {
         this.height = this.height*wh;
         this.width = this.width*wh;
 }
 else
 {
         this.height = this.height*ww;
         this.width = this.width*ww;
 }
}
```